# React change values of clicked array item

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

In my React component I have an array which will render linked social icons:

```
icons: { [
     { iconName: 'twitter', url: '#'},
     { iconName: 'facebook', url: '#'},
     { iconName: 'instagram', url: '#'},
] },
```

In render I'm showing all the social icon links from the array:

```
icons.map( ( icon, index ) => (
  <a key={ index }
    href='#'
    onClick={() => {
       setAttributes({ iconClicked: index });
    }}
  >                   
        <Icon icon={ icon.iconName } /> /* this just renders an svg icon */
  </a>
) )
```

When I click on a social icon, I want to be able to populate a form with the icon name and url and be able to change the values.

To do that, I'm first setting `itemClicked` to the index of the icon I clicked on (using `onClick` seen above).

**Note:** `itemClicked` as well as the `icons` array are state variables which update on change.

Next I'm trying to display the icon name in a select list and the url in a text input:

```
<SelectControl
  label="Icon Name"
  value={ icons[iconClicked].iconName }
  options={ [
      { label: __( 'Twitter' ), value: 'twitter' },
      { label: __( 'Facebook' ), value: 'facebook' },
      { label: __( 'Instagram' ), value: 'instagram' },
      { label: __( 'YouTube' ), value: 'youtube' },
  ] }
  onChange={( value ) => {
     const newIcon = icons[iconClicked].iconName;
     setAttributes({ newIcon: value });
  }}
/>

<TextControl
  label={ __( 'Enter URL' ) }
  value={ icons[iconClicked].url }
  onChange={( value ) => {
     const newUrl = icons[iconClicked].url;
     setAttributes({ newUrl: value });
  }}
/>
```

When I click any icon, the select and text control populate with the correct values but they do not update when I try to change the value. I do not get errors, but the initial values don't change when `onChange` is triggered.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Shouldnt it be icons.default[index ]? vs what you have  icons[index].

Icons info is under the default property

Comment: @varoons no, default just adds a default array. The code is part of the wordpress block api and that's how you define array properties

Comment: Ah k.. You should probably use internal state to update those values. The values will not change as they are always coming from your default items array. Set a state variable which you update when you change the text

Comment: I updated to code to simplify

Comment: Internal state is part of the api, so it works. I just didnt inlcude all the code, to simplify

Comment: What is `setAttributes`?

Comment: `setAttributes` updates the internal state of variables

Comment: So you don't use `setState`? Because React only updates the render if you use `setState`.

Comment: `setAttributes` does the same thing. That's just the synthax for the block api. States is not the issue, they work. I feel like I don't have the right syntax for arrays in react

Comment: It wonders me why you make icons as an object, with an array of objects? Why not just make it as an array of objects?

Comment: @CyberJunkie You need to show us full block code, for us to understand the problem better